# MySQL copiar datos de una columna de una tabla a otra columna en otra tabla con identificador

Tags: mysql, update

Hola quisera saber como puedo copiar los datos de una tabla a otra tabla pero que me identifique por un product_id unico.

Tengo muchos productos y lo que quiero es actualizar los precios en otra tabla

Tengo este codigo, pero lo hace para todos los productos y no para cada uno,lo hago en mysql5.7 espero me ayuden.

```
UPDATE sma_sale_items
       INNER JOIN sma_products
          ON product_id = product_id
    SET precio = price
```

Comment: Solo te falta agregar el `where <tu condicion>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una sub-select haciendo el join por ID de producto.

```
UPDATE sma_sale_items t1
SET t1.precio = (select price from sma_products p
                  where p1.product_id = t1.product_id)
WHERE t1.id_producto = XXX;
```

Cambia el 'XXX' por el ID que quieras actualizar de producto o por cualquier otra condición para hacer una actualización múltiple, por ejemplo, para actualizar todos los precios que no tienen valor.

```
UPDATE sma_sale_items t1
SET t1.precio = (select price from sma_products p
                  where p1.product_id = t1.product_id)
WHERE t1.precio is null;
```

Este enfoque debería funcionar en prácticamente todas las BBDD no sólo MySQL, el inner join en un update puede estar algo menos soportado.

Comment: y si yo quisiera actualizar todos los precios a los precios de mi nueva tabla por producto_id? se puede ?

Comment: en el ultimo apartado me dice            #1242 - Subconsulta retorna mas que 1 línea

Comment: estaba suponiendo que `product_id` era la PrimaryKey de `sma_products`, ¿ no es así? Entonces ayudaría conocer mejor el modelo de datos de ambas tablas